# Roark Junior suffers damage to groin

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, sin-city

In the movie, Sin City(I believe in the comic book as well), there is a scene in the beginning of the episode of “That Yellow Bastard”, where the character, Hartigan, after disarming Roark Junior, proceeds to shoot him directly in the groin, thereby disarming him of his second “weapon”. Later when Hartigan wakes in the hospital he is visited by senator Roark who then tells him that he spent a fortune replacing the “equipment” that Hartigan either severely damaged or shot off.

My question is this. To what extent can male genitalia be repaired or even replaced(if we’re strictly following the movie plot)?

Comment: Is this the proper SE to be asking this or should I be trying a science SE?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about real-world medical information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question very much depends on the damage done.

Reconstructive surgery is very much a thing.

However, there have been a [*few* successful transplantations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penis_transplantation)

> In April 2018, The New York Times reported that surgeons from Johns Hopkins, led by W. P. Andrew Lee, had performed the first penis transplant performed on a combat victim and the third successful penis transplant so far. This transplant also included the scrotum, but not the testicles, for ethical reasons. The patient's identity was not disclosed.[15]

To name one of them.

Sin City is also a fantasy movie set in the early 1900s, so one should expect a bit of [Suspension of Disbelief](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WillingSuspensionOfDisbelief) It doesn't matter if it's *actually* possible or not, what's important is that the surgery is what [made the villian.](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CreateYourOwnVillain) And if Hartigan would have just killed him, instead of 'punishing' him, he would have avoided the torture and deaths of countless women by *The Yellow Bastard*.